# Legend of Flow Direction calculated with processing toolbox QGIS (SAGA)

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, saga, flow-map

I tried to figure out the legend of the output for flow direction when I use the QGIS processing toolbox function from SAGA (Channel network and drainage basin). I get a raster with values from 0 to 7. The Taudem d8 uses an encoding from 1 to 8 that does not correspond with this result. Anybody knows how this is encoded?

Comment: Why not check [online documentation?](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.0/ta_channels_0.html)

Comment: Thanks. I already checked this documentation and other internet resources. This documentation also states that the range is from 1-8 which is not in line with the results I get (0-7). Is it a systematic shift or a different encoding?

Answer (score 10):

SAGA's flow directions are coded from North = 0 :

```
7 0 1
6   2
5 4 3
```

Each GIS has its codification :  for GRASS it's

```
3 2 1
4   8
5 6 7
```

and for ARcgis : http://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-flow-direction-works.htm