# Flow direction raster - 1-128 - QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I would like to know if there is a function in QGIS or R to calculate the flow direction in the sequence `1-2-4-8-16-32-64-128`

the functions I've used so far give values ​​from `1 to 8`, and I didn't want to change the values ​​manually because I didn't know if the directions would be equal

Comment: Since you mentioned flowdir as 1,2,4,8...128, you might be referring to the Arc* flow direction scheme. Note that Arc* (as well as SAGA) number directions clockwise, whereas TauDEM and GRASS GIS number direction CCW. Refer to this [SE post:](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254939/legend-of-flow-direction-calculated-with-processing-toolbox-qgis-saga) .  So first let us know what software you are using within QGIS to get the 1...8 numbering.

Comment: Please decide whether it is QGIS or R that you wish to ask about in this particular question. If it’s R then please include a code attempt.